# How do I generate the swagger file, swagger CLI isn't supported with .net 8

Tags: swagger, .net-8.0, post-build-event, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, post-build

Since swagger CLI (swashbuckle.aspnetcore.cli v6.5.0) isn't supported with .net 8 (yet), how do I generate the swagger file (Open API specifications file) in post build event in .net 8 project?

**I've tried** writing the swagger file programmatically using a custom helper method that reads the openAPI document using ISwaggerProvider service and then converts it to JSON.

```
internal static void SaveSwaggerJson(this IServiceProvider provider)
{
    ISwaggerProvider swaggerService = provider.GetRequiredService<ISwaggerProvider>();
    OpenApiDocument doc = swaggerService.GetSwagger("v1", null, "/");
    string swaggerFile = doc.SerializeAsJson(Microsoft.OpenApi.OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0);
    File.WriteAllText("swagger_v1.json", swaggerFile);
}
```

And then I called it in program.cs:

```
app.Services.SaveSwaggerJson();
```

**But** the issue associated with this is that during pipeline-build stage, I don't have the write access hence the generation of swagger.json fails/it doesn't appear in the artifacts library of the build pipeline.

I've gone through multiple stackoverflow threads and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: did you find any luck with this ?